# rust serde custom data format deserialize

Tags: rust, serde

I've got a Serializer for a custom data format that is raw binary and has no embedded type information, etc. So:

```
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct { a: u32, b:u32 }
```

Is stored as 2 32-bit raw values (big endian). I'm having trouble with the deserialization though. I'm not sure what to do in deserialize_struct

```
struct MyDeserializer<'de> {
  input: &'de [u8],
  offset: usize,
}

impl<'de, 'a> serde::Deserializer<'de> for &'a mut MyDeserializer<'de> {
  fn deserialize_struct<V>(self, _name: &'static str, _fields: &'static [&'static str], visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value>
  where V: serde::de::Visitor<'de>
  {
    // what do I do here?
  }
}
```

I looked at the expanded Deserialize derive and I can impl SeqAccess on MyDeserializer and based on T in next_element_seed() I can deserialize the next chunk of data. My naive thought is to

```
impl<'de> SeqAccess<'de> for Deserializer<'de> {
    type Error = super::Error;

    fn next_element_seed<T>(&mut self, seed: T) -> Result<Option<T::Value>>
    where
        T: serde::de::DeserializeSeed<'de>
    {
        let len = std::mem::size_of::<T::Value>();
        let start = self.offset;
        self.offset += len;
        Ok(Some(T::Value::from_be_bytes(self.input[start..self.offset])))
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        Some(self.input.len() - self.offset)
    }
}
```

But I can't call from_be_bytes on T::Value because it's not constrained.

I found num-traits with FromBytes and changed to

```
fn next_element_seed<T>(&mut self, seed: T) -> Result<Option<T::Value>>
where
    T: serde::de::DeserializeSeed<'de>,
    T::Value: FromBytes,
{
    let len = std::mem::size_of::<T::Value>();
    let start = self.offset;
    self.offset += len;
    let value: T::Value = FromBytes::from_be_bytes(&self.input[start..self.offset]);
    Ok(Some(value))
}
```

But I can't do that because the function has stricter requirements than the trait. I'm stuck on this now...

Comment: If the format has specific requirements for how the data is storage? If yes, you should tell us about them and how this data should be laid out. If not, consider using [`bincode`](https://docs.rs/bincode) or other existing serialization crate.

Comment: I did tell you the relevant format "Is stored as 2 32-bit raw values (big endian). " Bincode is a specific format, not raw binary.

Comment: But how should a slice be stored?

Comment: Also, `bincode` is as efficient as you can get, I believe. Do you have a specific use case for "raw binary"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement `SeqAccess` yourself or at all.

- Named structs don't want `SeqAccess`, they want `MapAccess`
- serde already has a convenience type for implementing `MapAccess`: `serde::de::value::MapDeserializer`.

You can use it like so:

```rust
// Somehow extract two u32 (a, b) from input, then:
let map = [("a", a), ("b", b)].into_iter();
let mut map = serde::de::value::MapDeserializer::new(map);
let visited = visitor.visit_map(&mut map)?;
map.end()?;
Ok(visited)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b7e93c54c5b159b94c816a8e29369c2)

---

Side note: I'm a bit unsure about your

```
struct MyDeserializer<'de> {
  input: &'de [u8],
  offset: usize,
}
```

Problem being that you have no way of communicating that you consumed 8 bytes to the outside of  `deserialize_struct`. I think it would be better to have a `&mut &[u8]`, which you could then update as `*self.input = &self.input[8..]`. Or you use a `&mut Cursor` or make `offset: &mut usize`, or similar.

---

Side note 2: If `MapDeserializer` is somehow too inflexible, you can implement `SecAccess` yourself. The trick to implementing `SeqAccess` or `MapAccess` is to not deserialize a concrete type in `next_*_seed` (that will get you stuck), but to construct another `Deserializer` (e.g. `MyDeserializer { input: &self.input[..4], … }`) and call `T::deserialize(&mut deserializer)` on that. That deserializer will then have one of its `deserialize_*` methods called (in your case `deserialize_u32`), and you can do the `from_be_bytes` there.